# How can I cache a sub 5MB config for free Google cloud function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a google cloud function that uses api to serve to users information. That said I shouldn’t make an api call for each request as specified by the API good practice I’m using, so I have to cache result.

I’d like to cache it to get fast access but also still use the free tier of google preferably (or any other free tier option that works well for the job).

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to understand your question, but I think you are trying to create an in-memory cache solution using cloud function. TL;DR this is not possible.

Cloud Functions should be stateless, please take a look at the [official documention](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec). The same rules also apply for Cloud Run.

However, you can use a combination of tools to achieve your goal, for example, [Redis Memorystore](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore), but this is not into the free tier.

Another option is maybe to use firestore to cache your results, however, I would check first your use case to make sure you don't run out of the free tier quickly.

Finding a free solution for a in-memory solution is very difficult IMO.

Cheers

Comment: It actually **is** possible to use a memory cache in Cloud Functions. It is quite common to initialize variables on the first run of the function, and you can also store data on the `/tmp` (RAM) disk.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen how do u make sure that your user will hit the same instance?

Comment: You can't. But *if* you hit the same instance, the instance data will still be there. See my answer: as it is quite common to cache data between calls. What isn't possible is storing state that can't be recalculated, but caching in OP's scenario is explicitly data that can be recalculated (by calling the API again).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen interesting, I appreciate it the clarification, I did this study in the past https://thecloudfunction.com/blog/scaling-google-cloud-functions-to-300-instances-in-one-minute/ and noticed that you rarely hit the same instance unless u have a significant amount of traffic in the same 15-20 mints timeline

Comment: True. And a valid comment. But all of that doesn't change the fact that you *can* cache data in Cloud Functions, and it is commonly done. For example: the Cloud Firestore client is caching a lot of information on its first connection, precisely so that subsequent calls can be handled faster. As does the Realtime Database client, and many of the other Firebase Admin SDKs.

Answer (score 0):

You can either keep the API result in memory, or on the `/tmp` disk (which is actually also stored in memory). Since the minimal memory size for a Cloud Functions image is 128MB, spending 5MB of that on cached API results seems reasonable.

As Andres answered: keep in mind that Cloud Functions are ephemeral and spin up and down as needed, so there's no saying how often a call to your Cloud Function will serve the cached results vs it calling the backend API.